# Find the biggest number from a file by bash

Tags: bash

I would like to find the biggest value from the file, and the file is as below:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
```

my code is as below(max.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

max=1
cat ./num | while read line; do
    if [ $line -gt $max ]; then
        max=$line
    fi
done
echo $max
```

but when I `bash -x max.sh`, the output is:

```
+ max=1
+ cat ./num
+ read line
+ '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
+ read line
+ '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
+ max=2
+ read line
+ '[' 3 -gt 2 ']'
+ max=3
+ read line
+ '[' 1 -gt 3 ']'
+ read line
+ '[' 2 -gt 3 ']'
+ read line
+ '[' 3 -gt 3 ']'
+ read line
+ '[' 4 -gt 3 ']'
+ max=4
+ read line
+ '[' 5 -gt 4 ']'
+ max=5
+ read line
+ '[' 1 -gt 5 ']'
+ read line
+ '[' 2 -gt 5 ']'
+ read line
+ '[' 3 -gt 5 ']'
+ read line
+ echo 1
1
```

it looks the max get the biggest value, but why the last echo of max is 1?

Comment: BTW, here are [`awk` one-liners](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170204/46316) for a similar task.

Comment: `sort -nr num | head -n1`

Comment: Also, [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: `sort -nr num | head -n1` is looks easier to understand, adopted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting value of `1` because you are using an unnecessary pipeline which is making `while` loop executing in a sub-shell hence value of `max` getting lost in child shell itself and you get preset value of `1` in parent shell after loop.

It is better to use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'min == "" || $1<min{min=$1} $1>max{max=$1} END{print min, max}' file

5
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit about the above?

Comment: It is pretty simple `awk`. For each record, It compares a variable `max` with `$1` and when we find `$1` greater than `max` then we reset `max` to `$1` again.

Comment: I suggest reading [awk guide](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) or a good tutorial.

Comment: if I wish to find out the smallest num, what the awk looks like?

Comment: See my updated answer for finding min and max